# Why I got another size of a component in IDE?

Tags: delphi, constructor, components, size, design-time

*Using Delphi 6 Prof.*

I created a bevel component for separation.

Because I used spacers with 8 pixel (width x height) I thought that I create this component, and when I put it on a Form, I need only to set Align - and that's all.

```
type
  TSSpacer = class(TBevel)
  public
    constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    //property Width default 8;
    //property Height default 8;
    property Shape default bsSpacer;
end;

constructor TSSpacer.Create(aOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  Shape := bsSpacer;
  Width := 8;
  Height := 8;
end;
```

But when I use this code (with or without "defaults") the result is 140 x 41 pixels in the IDE.

So why does it not size to 8 x 8? And what is also interesting: the default TBevel is 50 x 50.

What causes this resizing?

Comment: IMHO it's such kind of a design-time limitation (maybe it has something to do with grid dimensions, don't know). If you set e.g. 10x10 it's correctly created at design time. I would _hack it_ by changing the value back but don't know how e.g. in `SetBounds` determine that the component is in design time AND its creation has been finished (`Loaded` procedure is just for run-time). I've tried a quick (have no time :) debug and it seems that something in the property filler modifies these values. +1 anyway, interesting question!

Comment: If you set it to 10x10, it works, but if you set it to 8x8 it fails? Why would that make a difference, @Tlama?

Comment: @Rob, exactly; verified in D2007 and D2009. I would suspect some internal limits for design-time dimensions. 1x10 works, 1x9 don't; 10x1 works, 9x1 don't. Seems like there's a limit for both dimensions beeing less than 10, what is really strange (and it's not about grid size, I've set 8x8). At runtime you can do whatever you want, but after design-time constructor there's something what modifies the dimensions. It would be easy to override e.g. SetBounds but how do I determine that the component has been completely created (the SetBounds fires few times after constructor has finished).

Comment: In D2007 at least, the bounding box used to set the initial size of the a component is expanded to at least 10x10 to prevent a component from being unhittable in the designer. Once a component is created the bounding box is applied to the component. This allows the user to specify, by dragging, what the initial size of the component should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLama hits the nail in his comments: somehow the designer prevents components from becoming too small. Strange though that the designer does not set this minimum size (10 x 10), but instead seems to randomly set the size to arbitrary values: 140 x 41 in D6 as stated by OP, and 100 x 41 here in D7.

Well, since TBevel does use nor publish the `AutoSize` property, and that property name kind of relates to wished behaviour, I chose to stretch its use:

```
type
  TSSPacer = class(TBevel)
  protected
    procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  published
    property Shape default bsSpacer;
  end;

constructor TSSPacer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Shape := bsSpacer;
end;

procedure TSSPacer.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if AutoSize then
    inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, 8, 8)
  else
    inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;

procedure TSSPacer.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  AutoSize := (csDesigning in ComponentState) and (Parent = nil) and
    (AParent <> nil);
  inherited SetParent(AParent);
end;
```

This works here in D7, but a more reliable implementation might be:

```
  private
    FFixDesignSize: Boolean;

procedure TSSPacer.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if FFixDesignSize then
  begin
    inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, 8, 8);
    FFixDesignSize := False;
  end
  else
    inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;

procedure TSSPacer.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  FFixDesignSize := (csDesigning in ComponentState) and (Parent = nil) and
    (AParent <> nil);
  inherited SetParent(AParent);
end;
```

And to complete this answer with a call stack of dropping this control in the designer on a form:

```
- Before SetBounds
- After SetBounds
- Before SetBounds
- After SetBounds
- Before SetParent
    - Before SetBounds
    - After SetBounds
- After SetParent
- Before SetBounds
- After SetBounds
- Before SetParent
- After SetParent
```

But I think you should not rely on this specific order or number of calls: I suspect it might differ between Delphi versions.

Comment: BTW, SetParent isn't guarenteed to be called only once. It is called whenver the parent is changed.

Comment: @TLama I understand. I was responding to your "only once" comment not to the code as presented.

Answer (score 0):

Found an article that should explain it.. I think you need to override TControl's SetBounds.

Read more here http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/77

Comment: Can you please explain more? The article starts out, "If ... you need to catch or limit changes to Left, Top, Width, or Height." Why would we need to do either of those things just to set the *initial* size of the control?

Comment: @John, the `SetBounds` is fired few times after constructor finishes its job, so it seems there's some mechanism which prevents you to create the component with both dimensions less than 10x10 and you have to let the component to resize, so the simple test `if csDesigning in ComponentState then SetMyDefaults` in `SetBounds` is not enough. It would fix the problem but create another one, you won't be able to resize the component at design-time.

Comment: This isn't an answer unless you expand it to include content here. If the majority of the content is in an external link, it becomes meaningless if the external site is down or disappears. Please edit to be more specific; you can always link to the external site as a "more information" summary.